# Using Apache and mod_proxy in a forward proxy to convert http requests to https

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I've used both Apache and nginx as a reverse proxy performing HTTPS termination (listening on port 443) and forwarding the unencrypted HTTP traffic to Tomcat on port 8080 before.

However, what I need to do now is do the opposite. I have some client applications running on localhost that are (for simplicity) just talking plain HTTP. I want to be able to tell these client apps to use a forward proxy (on localhost) that will convert them to HTTPS and use a client-side certificate for the communication to the origin. Ie, the client will think it is communicating plain HTTP on port 80, but the traffic will actually leave the host as HTTPS on port 443.

Does anyone know how to configure mod_proxy to do this (or even if it is possible)?

At a further stage, I may need to configure the proxy to use different client certificates based on headers set by the client and also have mod_proxy use [RFC 5077](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077) (quick session resumption).

It doesn't have to be Apache (so if nginx or squid can do the function I'm happy with that) as long as it's not a resource hog. We already have Apache running as a reverse proxy anyway so it would be handy if Apache can do it.

Comment: did you had any luck with that one? was about to ask same question essentially but found yours and other with no answers... would appreciate any response. thanks!

Comment: No, we didn't find a simple solution to this unfortunately. Sorry.